# FTP/ BlobStorage Trigger to Azure Function App / Logic App

Tags: azure, triggers, azure-functions, eventtrigger, azure-logic-apps

Is there a trigger that can detect or fire an Azure Logic App or an Azure Function app when a new file is added or existing file is modified in my Azure FTP or BlobStorage
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, both triggers are supported for Function Apps:

- FTP trigger is supported by [Azure Functions External File bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-external-file)
- Blob trigger is supported by [Azure Functions Blob storage bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob)

Comment: I had seen this, but I did not try. I wanted to know if this function binding work by checking the ftp/blob storage every now and then with a cached list of files present earlier. Or is it some kind of trigger that calls the function from the storage. I'm sure Logic app does this kind of checking every now and then

Comment: @JinsPeter Functions runtime scans log files to watch for new or changed blobs. FTP is probably poll-based.

Comment: So, does that incur me cost without the function running? And I had read this word poll-based, which I did not understand clearly

Comment: @JinsPeter On Consumption Plan - no cost if you add no files.

Comment: and poll based meaning??/

Comment: Poll based refers to polling or polled operation which means that client application (ftp trigger) has to actively monitor status as a synchronous operation (in this case FTP server folder for new files). You can change in ftp trigger settings how often ftp server's folder is checked (per day, every hour, etc).

Comment: It seems that in 2021 there is no longer an FTP binding

Comment: See this project [WebJobs.Extensions.Ftp](https://github.com/StefH/WebJobs.Extensions.Ftp) which implements a Ftp Trigger (on a new FtpFile, FtpFile[], FtpStream and FtpStream[]) and Ftp Bindings (on IAsyncCollector, IFtpClient, FtpFile and FtpStream)